# Sql Query Take too much time to execute in stored procedure with (nolock)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query which takes too much time to execute. Actually this query fetches records from millions record. Please suggest me the solution which reduce the execution time of SQL query. The query is given below.

```
SELECT 
   e.emailAddress, em.employeeId 
FROM   
   Email e with (Nolock), employee em with (Nolock)
WHERE  
   e.emailAddress = em.email 
   AND em.employeeId = @employeeId
```

Comment: If you are using `with (Nolock)`, then you are using SQL Server. I'm removing the mysql tag.

Comment: Check the execution plan and see where the issue is. I am guessing you are having a problem with a non indexed table. The Execution plan can tell you that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 4):

First, it is better to write your query as an explicit `join`, rather than using implicit join syntax:

```
SELECT e.emailAddress, em.employeeId 
FROM   Email e with (Nolock) join
       employee em with (Nolock)
       ON e.emailAddress = em.email 
WHERE em.employeeId = @employeeId;
```

To make this query run best, you want indexes.  The first that comes to mind is `employee(employeeId, emailaddress)`.

Second, doesn't this query do what you want?

```
SELECT em.email, em.employeeId 
FROM employee em with (Nolock)
WHERE em.employeeId = @employeeId;
```

This query should run quite fast with the aforementioned index.